# A-frame random animation delay

Tags: animation, three.js, 3d, aframe, webvr

I am creating a scene using A-frame (https://aframe.io) and I'm currently using an animation in my scene. I'm wondering how I can randomize the delay on my animation so the animation delays from a random amount from 0 to 2 seconds. How can this be done? My current code:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      
      
      <!--Animte the box with a ranom delay from 0 - 2 seconds. -->
      <a-box position="-1 1.6 -5" animation="property: position; delay: 1000; to: 1 8 -10; dur: 2000; easing: linear; loop: true" color="tomato"></a-box>

      <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

I currently have the delay set to 1000 (1 second since the delay is in milliseconds). What should happen instead is the delay should be a random amount from 0 - 2000 since 2000 milliseconds is 2 seconds.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Random delay only at the start - first cycle

Register the a-box component with a custom one that will do the math and apply it to the animation on the a-box `<a-box position="-1 1.6 -5" random-delay animation color="tomato"></a-box>`.

1. Building the [custom aframe component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#sidebar):

```
    AFRAME.registerComponent('random-delay', {
        init: function (el) {
         // this.el points to the element the component is placed on 
         var el = this.el;

        }
    });
```

2. Set your min and max values

```
    AFRAME.registerComponent('random-delay', {
        init: function (el) {
            var el = this.el;
            var min = 0;
            var max = 2000;

        }
    });
```

3. `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min` returns an integer random number between min and max and than we build the string for the animation:

```
    AFRAME.registerComponent('random-delay', {
        init: function (el) {
            var el = this.el;
            var min = 0;
            var max = 2000;

            // generates a random number between the set min and max
            var delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            var animation = `property: position; delay: ${delay}; from: -1 1.6 -5; to: 1 8 -10; dur: 2000; easing: linear; loop: true`

        }
    });
```

4. Apply the animation string with the delay generated with [.setAttribue()](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#adding-a-component-with-setattribute):

```
    AFRAME.registerComponent('random-delay', {
        init: function (el) {
            var el = this.el;
            var min = 0;
            var max = 2000;

            // generates a random number between the set min and max
            var delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            // builds the string for the animation
            var animation = `property: position; delay: ${delay}; to: 1 8 -10; dur: 2000; easing: linear; loop: true`

            // updating the animation component with the .setAttribute() function
            el.setAttribute('animation', animation)

        }
    });
```

### Random delay on every animation cycle

1. place these lines of code into a new function:

```
function setAnimation(min, max) {
    // generates a random number between the set min and max
    var delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    var animation = `property: position; delay: ${delay}; from: -1 1.6 -5; to: 1 8 -10; dur: 2000; easing: linear; `
    console.log(delay);
    // updating the animation component with the .setAttribute function
    el.setAttribute('animation', animation)
}
```

2. At every [animationcomplete](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/animation.html#api3_animationcomplete) event set a new animation with the function we created

```
function setAnimation(min, max) {
    // generates a random number between the set min and max
    var delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    var animation = `property: position; delay: ${delay}; from: -1 1.6 -5; to: 1 8 -10; dur: 2000; easing: linear; `
    console.log(delay);
    // updating the animation component with the .setAttribute function
    el.setAttribute('animation', animation)
}
```

The result should look something like this:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('random-delay', {
        init: function (el) {
            // this.el points to the element the component is placed on 
            var el = this.el;
            let min = 0;
            let max = 2000;
            // initial animation
            setAnimation(min, max)

            function setAnimation(min, max) {
                // generates a random number between the set min and max
                let delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                let animation = `property: position; delay: ${delay}; from: -1 1.6 -5; to: 1 8 -10; dur: 2000; easing: linear; `
                console.log(delay);
                // updating the animation component with the .setAttribute function
                el.setAttribute('animation', animation)
            }
            el.addEventListener('animationcomplete', () => {
                setAnimation(min, max)
            });
        }
    });
</script>

<body>
    <a-scene>
        <a-box position="-1 1.6 -5" random-delay animation autoplay color="tomato">
        </a-box>

        <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
        <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
</body>

</html>
```